# submit multiple indexed buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am building a chatbot, there are multiple message bubbles in a page, I want to have a rating button at the corner of the chatbot response bubble and submit the rating to the database. Here I try to index each rating button, but I'm not sure how to finish the event function. The questions are in the comment of function handleThumbupSubmit(event)
html for user input

```
function appendMessage(text, message_index) {
      //   Simple solution for small apps
      randomeIndex = getRandomInt(100000000)

      //get a random number for message index. The page contains multiple feedback forms, we need to index all of them in order to store them 
      message_index = randomeIndex
  
     
      if (name === "    Chatbot"){
      
      const msgHTML = `


  <div class="ratings">
   
  <div class="msg-bubble">
   
    
    <div class="rating-img">
    <button type="submit" class="thumbup" id="thumbup-${message_index}"></button>
    <button type="submit" class="thumbDown" id="thumbDown-${message_index}"></button>
    </div>

  </div>

    <div class="msg-text">${text}</div>  
    

</div>
</div>
</div>
`;
```

This is the function to control the button being clicked, I'm not sure how to index the button so that when it's clicked I know exactly which button is clicked.

```
let clickedThumbUP = false;

let rating_up = $(".thumbup").click(function(){
  
  //let rating_up  = checkRating(clickedThumbUP);

  clickedThumbUP = !clickedThumbUP; // Toggle state on each click

  if (clickedThumbUP === true) {
    $(this).toggleClass("thumbup thumb-up-black");
    return true

  }  

  else{
    $(this).toggleClass("thumbup thumb-up-black");
    return false

  }
  
});
```

Here are the event functions that handle the button submission, I'm not sure what is the best way to handle the submission so that the database would show the response (true/ false) of each indexed button.

```
function handleThumbupSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // get the button  id 
  const ThumbupId = event.target.id;
 
  //Not sure how to call the indexed button heres??
  if (indexedButton == true) {
  sessionStorage.setItem("rating_up",JSON.stringify(rating_up));
  
  //Do I need to reset the button to false after submission?
 
  console.log("submitted rating!!!!")

}

  else{
    var feedback_content = "no feedback";
  }
}


document.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {

  console.log("eventlistener triggered")

  
  if (event.target && event.target.classList.contains("thumbup")) {
    handleThumbupSubmit(event);
  }


});
```

Here's an example of my datastructure.

```
data_store = {
    "users": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "email": "john.doe@example.com",
            "chat_history": {
                "message": "123",
                "thumbup": 
                    "thumbup_id1": "true",
                    "thumbup_id2": "false",
                "thumbdown":
                     "thumbdown_id2": "false",
                     "thumbdown_id2": "false",
              ...
            }
        ]
```

Comment: Where is `indexedButton` set?

Comment: that is my question too, not sure how to set this indexedButton

Comment: `event.target` will be the button they clicked on, is that what you need?

Comment: yes @Barmar you are right

Comment: Then what's the problem? This is basic JS event handling, should be covered in any tutorial.

Comment: It looks like you already know that, you use it in `addEventListener()`.

Comment: Are you asking how to get `message_index` from the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting `message_index` in the ID, put it in a `data` attribute.

```
    <button type="submit" class="thumbup" data-index="${message_index}"></button>
    <button type="submit" class="thumbDown" data-index="${message_index}"></button>
```

Then in `handleThumbEvent()` you can use `event.target.dataset.index` to get the message index.

Comment: I've just edited the question, I think my question is I'm how to handle the click function so that it reflects which button is clicked.

Comment: I told you how. `event.trarget.dataset.index` will tell you the index corresponding to the button that was clicked.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, it will be `$(this).data("index")`